# How do I add columns to a view?

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-view

Is there a way to add new columns and update them in the view?

The columns are not in any table; I want to select few columns from a table then add few new columns and update them.

I tried `ALTER VIEW` to add columns but it gave me an error:

> Cannot alter 'viewName' because it is not a table.

Comment: Delete the view and create it from scratch, again, with additional columns.

Answer (score 6):

See the [SQL Server `ALTER VIEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846.aspx) documentation.

You don't add columns to a new view, you just include the entire query to your view.

For exmaple, if I had:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView 
AS
SELECT UserID, UserName
FROM Users
```

And then wanted to add `DateCreated` to my select list, I would write:

```
ALTER VIEW MyView 
AS
SELECT UserID, UserName, DateCreated
FROM Users
```

Alternately, you can just `DROP` the view and `CREATE` it with the new columns as well.

Comment: +1 for understanding the OP's question... I didn't get it until I read your answer and realized they were trying to `Alter View Add Column`. This wasn't clear from the post, but I believe is definitely what they were looking for.